# Django REST Framework serializer PrimaryKeyRelatedField() not adding object in GET response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django 2.x` and `Django REST Framework.

I have **models.py** with content as

```
class ModeOfPayment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField()

class AmountGiven(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    mode_of_payment = models.ForeignKey(
        ModeOfPayment,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        null=True
    )
```

and **serializers.py**

```
class AmountGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mode_of_payment = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ModeOfPayment.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = AmountGiven
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id', 'contact', 'amount', 'mode_of_payment', 
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        mode_of_payment = validated_data.pop('mode_of_payment')
        instance.mode_of_payment_id = mode_of_payment.id
        return instance
```

This works fine as I'm able to update `mode_of_payment` field. But in response when calling `amount_given` doesn't contain parameters of `mode_of_payment` object.

the response is like

```
{
    "id": "326218dc-66ab-4c01-95dc-ce85f226012d",
    "contact": {
        "id": "b1b87766-86c5-4029-aa7f-887f436d6a6e",
        "first_name": "Prince",
        "last_name": "Raj",
        "user": 3
    },
    "amount": 3000,
    "mode_of_payment": "0cd51796-a423-4b75-a0b5-80c03f7b1e65",
}
```

while removing the line

```
mode_of_payment = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ModeOfPayment.objects.all())
```

does add the `mode_of_payment` parameters with response but this time this does not update the `mode_of_payment` field on `amount_given`.

why `mode_of_payment` data is not contained even when `depth` is set to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create `ModeOfPaymentSerializer` and use it in AmountGivenSerializer's `to_representation()` method:

```
class ModeOfPaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModeOfPayment
        fields = (
            'id', 'title',
        )

class AmountGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mode_of_payment = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ModeOfPayment.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = AmountGiven
        fields = (
            'id', 'contact', 'amount', 'mode_of_payment', 
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        mode_of_payment = validated_data.pop('mode_of_payment')
        instance.mode_of_payment_id = mode_of_payment.id
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, value):
        data = super().to_representation(value)  
        mode_serializer = ModeOfPaymentSerializer(value.mode_of_payment)
        data['mode_of_payment'] = mode_serializer.data
        return data
```